# More efficient solution using a loop for white space replacment javascript

Tags: javascript, loops

```
this can be found in other forums and posts like what people have said thank you.
```

I am trying to make a function using a loop that replaces the " " with %20 but if their is white space before and after the string the " " does not get replaced with %20 I have the solution here using a loop which is required I am just wondering If I can make it more precise and concise any help would be appreciated.

```
console.log(urlEncode("Hello World"));
console.log(urlEncode(" Hello World "));
console.log(urlEncode("This is my Hello World Program"));

Hello%20World
Hello%20World <--- if their is space before or after it does not count
This%20is%20my%20Hello%20World%20Program
```

Comment: `const urlEncode = text => text.trim().replace(/ /g, '%20');`

Comment: are you looking for this? `const urlEncode = text => encodeURIComponent(text.trim());`

Comment: Why is a loop required? See above comments, a lot easier/cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
const urlEncode = function(text) {
    return text.trim().replace(/\b \b/g, '%20')
}
```

This uses the built in replace method and matches a space surrounded by two non-spaces.

If you really want to use a loop:

```
const urlEncode = function(text) {
    const n = text.length;
    const start = text[0] === ' ' ? 1 : 0;
    const end = text[n - 1] === ' ' ? n - 1 : n;
    let result = "";

    for (let i = start; i < end; i++) {
         result += text[i] == ' ' ? '%20' : text[i];
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: return += text[i] == ' ' ? '%20' : text[i]; 
shows an error but thank you for the solution with the loop appreciate it I know this can be done with replace but the question wants it to be done with a loop once again thank you

Comment: @David that should be `result += text[i] == ' ' ? '%20' : text[i];` (not `return +=`). I should have used === instead of ==.

Answer (score 1):

See Thomas' comment. Using javascripts native encodeURIComponent is probably the easiest and safest.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Answer (score 1):

I am sure this has been answered before you should do a bit more research friend but here is an option.

```
const urlEncode = (str) => {
  return str.trim().replace(/\s/g, '%20');
}
```

edit: ahh gotcha missed the by looping part

```
const urlEncode = (str) => {
  str = str.trim();
  let encodedStr = '';
  let index = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if(str[i] === ' ') {
      encodedStr += str.slice(index, i)+'%20';
      index = i+1;
    }
  }
  return encodedStr + str.split(' ').pop();
};
```

I still had to use split though. I'll keep thinking.

Edit3: Got it!

```
const urlEncode = (str) => {
  str = str.trim();
  let encodedStr = '';
  let index = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if(str[i] === ' ') {
      encodedStr += str.slice(index, i)+'%20';
      index = i+1;
    }
  }
  return encodedStr + str.slice(index, str.length);
};
```

If you have any questions feel free to ask!

Comment: I know this is the fast way but it has to be done using a loop

Answer (score 0):

```
function urlEncode(txt){
  let text = txt.split("");
  let acc = "";
  for(let i = 0; i < text.length; i++){
    let curr = text[i];
    let ret = curr;
    let inx = i;
    if(curr === " " && (inx === 0 || (inx === txt.length - 1))){
      ret = " ";
    } else if(curr === " "){
      ret = "%20";
    }
    acc += ret;
  }
  return acc;
}
```